# R: ggvis - gray background (as ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggvis

I want the ggplot2 look and feel within Ggvis. Is there a way to achieve this within ggvis?

[image]

I have this from ggvis:

[image]

Note:
1) Don't like the white background (better the gray one from ggplot2
2) As you see, the bars have an blackline outlined. How to get ride of it?

My code:

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente %>%
        ggvis(~Fuentes, ~sessions) %>%
          layer_bars(width = 0.8, fill = ~Fuentes)
```

My data:

```
    as.data.frame(structure(list(date = structure(c(1417410000, 1417410000, 1417410000, 
1417410000, 1417410000, 1417410000, 1417496400, 1417496400, 1417496400, 
1417496400, 1417496400, 1417496400, 1417496400, 1417582800, 1417582800, 
1417582800, 1417582800, 1417582800, 1417582800, 1417582800, 1417669200, 
1417669200, 1417669200, 1417669200, 1417669200, 1417669200, 1417669200, 
1417755600, 1417755600, 1417755600, 1417755600, 1417755600, 1417755600, 
1417842000, 1417842000, 1417842000, 1417842000, 1417842000, 1417842000, 
1417842000, 1417928400, 1417928400, 1417928400, 1417928400, 1417928400, 
1417928400, 1417928400, 1418014800, 1418014800, 1418014800, 1418014800, 
1418014800, 1418014800, 1418014800, 1418101200, 1418101200, 1418101200, 
1418101200, 1418101200, 1418101200, 1418101200, 1418187600, 1418187600, 
1418187600, 1418187600, 1418187600, 1418187600, 1418187600, 1418274000, 
1418274000, 1418274000, 1418274000, 1418274000, 1418274000, 1418274000, 
1418360400, 1418360400, 1418360400, 1418360400, 1418360400, 1418360400, 
1418360400, 1418446800, 1418446800, 1418446800, 1418446800, 1418446800, 
1418446800, 1418446800, 1418533200, 1418533200, 1418533200, 1418533200, 
1418533200, 1418533200, 1418533200, 1418619600, 1418619600, 1418619600, 
1418619600, 1418619600, 1418619600, 1418619600, 1418706000, 1418706000, 
1418706000, 1418706000, 1418706000, 1418706000, 1418706000, 1418792400, 
1418792400, 1418792400, 1418792400, 1418792400, 1418792400, 1418792400, 
1418878800, 1418878800, 1418878800, 1418878800, 1418878800, 1418878800, 
1418878800, 1418965200, 1418965200, 1418965200, 1418965200, 1418965200, 
1418965200, 1418965200, 1419051600, 1419051600, 1419051600, 1419051600, 
1419051600, 1419051600, 1419051600, 1419138000, 1419138000, 1419138000, 
1419138000, 1419138000, 1419138000, 1419224400, 1419224400, 1419224400, 
1419224400, 1419224400, 1419224400, 1419224400, 1419310800, 1419310800, 
1419310800, 1419310800, 1419310800, 1419310800, 1419397200, 1419397200, 
1419397200, 1419397200, 1419397200, 1419397200, 1419397200, 1419483600, 
1419483600, 1419483600, 1419483600, 1419483600, 1419483600, 1419483600, 
1419570000, 1419570000, 1419570000, 1419570000, 1419570000, 1419570000, 
1419656400, 1419656400, 1419656400, 1419656400, 1419656400, 1419656400, 
1419742800, 1419742800, 1419742800, 1419742800, 1419742800, 1419742800, 
1419742800, 1419829200, 1419829200, 1419829200, 1419829200, 1419829200, 
1419829200, 1419915600, 1419915600, 1419915600, 1419915600, 1419915600, 
1419915600, 1419915600, 1420002000, 1420002000, 1420002000, 1420002000, 
1420002000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Lima"), 
    Fuentes = c("Adwords", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", 
    "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", 
    "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", 
    "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", "Directo", "Email", "Referencias", 
    "SEO", "Social Media", "Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Directo", 
    "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media"), sessions = c(10L, 
    326L, 18L, 527L, 999L, 52L, 3L, 7L, 324L, 19L, 498L, 933L, 
    44L, 5L, 12L, 363L, 15L, 546L, 1206L, 202L, 7L, 12L, 1122L, 
    27L, 1249L, 5168L, 607L, 17L, 432L, 22L, 527L, 1553L, 637L, 
    5L, 5L, 356L, 16L, 507L, 1901L, 487L, 4L, 8L, 312L, 30L, 
    500L, 1622L, 370L, 3L, 11L, 341L, 18L, 504L, 1312L, 352L, 
    2L, 13L, 1188L, 33L, 682L, 2008L, 1508L, 3L, 15L, 1086L, 
    36L, 646L, 2124L, 380L, 3L, 11L, 355L, 17L, 383L, 1054L, 
    236L, 2L, 9L, 321L, 15L, 370L, 1118L, 245L, 7L, 9L, 259L, 
    13L, 332L, 1261L, 230L, 3L, 7L, 539L, 9L, 626L, 2336L, 256L, 
    1L, 12L, 292L, 8L, 386L, 1070L, 220L, 1L, 12L, 278L, 9L, 
    393L, 1129L, 22L, 1L, 16L, 521L, 18L, 665L, 2400L, 20L, 1L, 
    13L, 204L, 7L, 258L, 789L, 11L, 2L, 12L, 253L, 6L, 277L, 
    803L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 262L, 8L, 324L, 960L, 9L, 3L, 442L, 15L, 
    516L, 1890L, 16L, 2L, 14L, 249L, 8L, 240L, 688L, 11L, 15L, 
    182L, 7L, 200L, 548L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 171L, 7L, 183L, 480L, 5L, 
    1L, 3L, 176L, 5L, 231L, 506L, 6L, 15L, 283L, 18L, 322L, 786L, 
    11L, 13L, 210L, 9L, 232L, 649L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 258L, 4L, 306L, 
    891L, 9L, 4L, 183L, 10L, 293L, 634L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 188L, 9L, 
    244L, 566L, 11L, 134L, 1L, 176L, 453L, 4L)), .Names = c("date", 
"Fuentes", "sessions"), row.names = c(NA, -208L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(date), drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: For some reason, ggvis does not recognize the "ñ" from "Campañas". How to make it appear?

Comment: not sure you need to put the factor() in this code - it's already categorical

Comment: @jalapic, it is better not to use factor(). It was giving me problems within shiny. In Shiny, it ploted it right the first time, but after changing the datarangeInput the plot dissapearded. This not happens if you take off the ~factor() part. I've changed my code to reflect this.

Comment: I believe that by playing around with `layer_rects()` you might be able to alter the background plot look.

Comment: Did you test your code in a fresh session? `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Fuentes' not found`

Comment: @jbaums, it was corrected. Please, try it again.

Comment: You're still missing a tilde. Should be `ggvis(~Fuentes, ~sessions)`. It's best to test that your code works :)

Comment: Sorry for that. Now it is okay.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ggvis does not currently support what you are trying to do.

Comment: @miles2know, i thought there would be a function called theme() or something,  but apperantly there isn't.

Comment: @OmarGonzales not sure about the background, but use `stroke := NA` (or really any string that's not a color) to get rid of the borders

Answer (score 11):

If your output is a Shiny application or Shiny document, you can change the background color with some css. Note that this will only work correctly when the ggvis is displayed as svg (not canvas). Also note that it will not display correctly in the Rstudio viewer. Add this somewhere in the document before the ggvis is created:

```
<style type="text/css">
rect.background {
  fill: #E6E6E6 !important;
}
</style>
```

Then to get white gridlines and to remove the bar borders, your code should look like this

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente %>%
        ggvis(~Fuentes, ~sessions) %>%
          layer_bars(width = 0.8, fill = ~Fuentes, strokeWidth := 0) %>%
          add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(grid = list(stroke = "white"))) %>%
          add_axis("y", properties = axis_props(grid = list(stroke = "white")))
```

Edit: Here's a minimal .Rmd document showing what to do. Open this in Rstudio and click "Run document" to see the results.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

<style type="text/css">
rect.background {
  fill: #E6E6E6 !important;
}
</style>

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~cyl, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_bars(width = 0.8, fill:= "slateblue", strokeWidth := 0) %>%
  add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(grid = list(stroke = "white"))) %>%
  add_axis("y", properties = axis_props(grid = list(stroke = "white")))
```
````